# Adverse Possession Law: Two Properties

Tags: real-estate, adverse-possession

Can one acquire by the law of adverse possession two different buildings with two different lot numbers and owners that are commercial buildings?

Comment: Is "that are commercial buildings" intended to modify "owners" or "buildings"?

Answer (score 1):

### Possibly

However in most jurisdictions adverse possession requires **actual** possession of the property in question, and the possession must be continuous. The actions of the adverse possessor must be such as to satisfy these and other requirements.

Comment: That's a good point. I had assumed OP meant consecutively, but if he means concurrently then there might be a feasibility issue.

Comment: @colin I wonder if adverse possiionb can be exercised through an agent or employee, or if the claimant has to be personally present. Perhaps that should be a separate questrion

Comment: yeah that's a really good question. Another thing would be how often the caselaw requires that the adverse possessor actually set two feet on the property for it to be continuous. The feasibility would also turn on how close to each other the properties in OP's hypo are. If they're right next to each other, maybe the adverse possessor can set up a tent and sleep with his head on one property and feet on the other!

Comment: Some jurisdictions also require that you (the adverse possessor) pay the property taxes.